# DataFrame not displaying all missing values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, machine-learning

my DataFrame has columns that have missing values. but only 4 columns show that I have missing values while other don't.

```
 0   Zone      15511 non-null  object   
 1   District  15511 non-null  object  
 2   id        15511 non-null  int64   
 3   Year      15511 non-null  int64   
 4   Sex       15511 non-null  object  
 5   OT        15511 non-null  object  
 6   Ext       15511 non-null  object   
 7   Irrg      15511 non-null  object   
 8   ST        15511 non-null  object    
 9   WS        15339 non-null  float64
```

for example OT column has missing value on my excel sheet but it does't appear to have missing values here.

what am I missing?

Comment: can you show those null values in the OT column?

Comment: also can you add the code that gives you this result to the question?

Comment: Hi Desta - welcome to Stack Overflow! While we appreciate concise, direct answers, we also do need enough context (preferrably the code) on your issue to understand how the issue was produced. See this guide on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Specifically for this question, we need to know how you're reading the data (`pd.read_csv`? what arguments? etc) and what/where the missing values in your data *should* look like. Good luck!

Comment: missing = data_final.isnull().sum()
print(missing)

Comment: and it shows meZone           0
District       0
id             0
Year           0
Sex            0
OT             0
Irrg           0
Ext            0
ST             0
WS           172
Damage         0
CD             0
FT          2554
PD             0
F_Used         0
FRT            1
CNFT        1165
FA           181
Yield          0
Arain          0
AMIT           0
AMXT           0

Comment: and in my excel, there are a lot of nul value on Ext, OT

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is open the file and identify those values that represent a null value, for example an empty string you consider null but isn't actually a null object.

when you have identified those values that are representative of an absent value; you iterate through that column and test for that condition, if true replace it with a null object.

Comment: missing = data_final.isnull().sum()
print(missing)

Comment: can you give me un example

Comment: show me a row with a OT value that you consider null.